# MSAL redirects when web api is called in Angular Application

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-angular

I am using B2c with an Angular application hosted in Azure Storage Static Website and an Angular functions application.

Using the code below I can see that I appear to be logged in. Where isLoggedIn = true.

```
 await this.msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise();
    let isLoggedIn = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;
```

However, as soon as I make a web call I get redirected to the redirection URL of my app (the login screen is not shown).

I was hoping someone might have an idea of how I could troubleshoot this, either by exposing more logs or different configurations I might look at that could cause this behavior.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/redirects.md. It's been so long since I used this, and don't have access to the code, but I believe we had an interceptor set up a few years ago, as ugly as it was, to bypass this issue.

Comment: Show code snippet of calling API.

Comment: Is the webapi that you're calling also protected by AAD? Have you setup protected routes so the MSAL intercepter can it job?